# How to force pandas read_csv to ignore semicolon in between actual delimiter?

Tags: csv, pandas, dataframe, delimiter

In a csv you have the following - as you can see in the third row the second column has a semicolon -

```
   /path/to/file,2,9/15/2016
   /path/to/file,3,9/15/2016
   /path/to/file,2;3,9/15/2016
```

So pandas read_csv treats that semicolon as a delimiter (even if I specify sep=',') and you get -

```
/path/to/file      2        9/15/2016
/path/to/file      2        9/15/2016
/path/to/file      2        3                9/15/2016
```

How to make read_csv ignore the semicolon? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Can you also provide your code?
I've created the following csv and py files, there is no delimiter in the code and it worked.

info.csv

```
path,number,date
/path/to/file,2,9/15/2016
/path/to/file,3,9/15/2016
/path/to/file,2;3,9/15/2016
```

test.py

```
import pandas
t = pandas.read_csv('info.csv')
print(t)
```

This is the output:

```
            path number       date
0  /path/to/file      2  9/15/2016
1  /path/to/file      3  9/15/2016
2  /path/to/file    2;3  9/15/2016
```